# Display cursor in AutoCompleteTextView Android HoneyComb Action bar

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have placed an Android AutoCompleteTextView in Honeycomb action bar. The problem is even if the AutoCompleteTextView has focus, it does not show the cursor, so end-user thinks that the box does not have focus.

Answer (score 4):

Add these attributes to your AutoCompleteTextView, to make the cursor black:

```
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165217/1267112