# Text color of SearchView in ActionBar with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to change the color of a text in an ActionBarSherlock `SearchView`, so I found this on StackOverflow:

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
searchText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

But the problem is that `searchText` is null always. Also I tried with `search_src_text` (no `abs__`) - again, `searchText` is `null`.

I use Sherlock for my ActionBar (having custom view for the actionbar) but I also want the text color of the search view to be changed.

Anything I don't get?

Comment: How does your layout look like and on which version of Android is your app running? It's quite common to add and apply some custom styles instead of assigning them programmatically. `abs__...` identifiers are only (potentially) useful on pre-Honeycomb devices.

Comment: my actionbar's custom view layout is simple LinearLayout which contains two imageview's. The Android I run the app is 4.2..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget check this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change and apply your styles as follows:

1. Overwrite `SearchViewStyle` that defines relevant style.

   ```
   <style name="SearchViewStyle" 
          parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.SearchAutoCompleteTextView">
       <item name="android:textColor">myTextColor</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Add this style definition to your app theme.

   ```
   <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
       ...
       <item name="searchAutoCompleteTextView">@style/SearchViewStyle</item>
       ...
   </style>
   ```
3. Apply this theme in your Manifest (`android:theme="CustomTheme"`).

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

*p.s.* search for `SearchViewStyle` in ABS style definitions (XML files). This way you can follow up available styles using Ctrl+click on definitions.

Comment: Any advice on how to get the cursor to be white as well?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382571/display-cursor-in-autocompletetextview-android-honeycomb-action-bar or that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527420/custom-cursor-color-in-searchview ?

Answer (score 0):

other way, work for me

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

        AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
        searchText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
.....................
}
```