# Set text colour of android.widget.SearchView

Tags: java, android

I am adding a `android.widget.SearchView` to a view in code but I cannot find how to set the text colour for this.

```
SearchView = new SearchView(getContext());
```

I see that there are methods to set the text alignment and direction.

I also see that I can set the background colour and tint but nothing for the foreground.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923442/text-color-of-searchview-in-actionbar-with-actionbarsherlock

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar this is not in an actionbar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321129/is-it-possible-to-change-the-textcolor-on-an-android-searchview

Comment: int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: i think u got check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321129/is-it-possible-to-change-the-textcolor-on-an-android-searchview

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar I also found that and it seems to work. Just pop it in an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null,
null);
TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

[Is it possible to change the textcolor on an Android SearchView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321129/is-it-possible-to-change-the-textcolor-on-an-android-searchview)

Comment: Not my ideal solution as it feels like a hack but I will go with it for now

Comment: can u give me your mail id